# Why does an async method not return the awaitable immediately?

Tags: c#, async-await

I had thought this was a reasonable pattern to use to call WebClient DownloadData asynchronously in an event handler:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    //wc.Proxy = null;
    byte[] bytes = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync("http://www.google.com");
    label1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```

But I find DownloadDataTaskAsync blocks for about 5 seconds before returning (unless the wc.Proxy = null statement is uncommented). What's the point of a method being awaitable if it can at a whim perform non-trivial work before even returning the task?

Presumably this means to be safe I should **never** call xAsync methods as above but instead should always wrap them in a Task.Run() myself to be sure. Or not?

Comment: You are waiting for the Async to complete... (With the await keyword)

Comment: No, an `Async` method really *should* return the task itself almost immediately. (I assume you're really talking about the method blocking, not the task it returns?) This may just be a WebClient bug.

Comment: If you don't set the proxy null or a value it tries to auto detect it which takes up to 30 seconds, that's probably the cause of the 5 second wait and nothing to do with async. You absolutely should call async methods as above to free up resources while the IO activity takes place.

Comment: yes it looks like DownloadDataTaskAsync wraps HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse which in turn calls ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(...) before it returns which locks up for a few seconds if the passed in proxy is not null, at least on my machine, probably for the reason Mant101 says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue with `WebClient`/`HttpWebRequest`: the proxies and DNS lookups are always done synchronously. This is a bug, but Microsoft has pretty much decided not to fix it for backwards compatibility reasons.

The first thing I'd recommend is to use `HttpClient`. If that doesn't work and you *need* asynchrony, then you can wrap the call in `Task.Run`.

Comment: ok thanks, that makes sense. I was warned to use HttpClient not WebClient in the first place, I should have listened...

Comment: How does `HttpClient` solve this issue? It uses async DNS lookups?

Comment: The `HttpClient` for the desktop .NET wraps `HttpWebRequest` within a thread pool request, so (as of this writing) it's using a kind of brute-force to force the DNS/proxy stuff to be asynchronous. Not ideal, but it works. And I'm not sure if `HttpClient` does (or has to do) this on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync is calling HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse

MSDN points out:

> The BeginGetResponse method requires some synchronous setup tasks to
>   complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket connection,
>   for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. **As a result,
>   this method should never be called on a user interface (UI) thread**
>   because it might take considerable time (up to several minutes
>   depending on network settings) to complete the initial synchronous
>   setup tasks before an exception for an error is thrown or the method
>   succeeds.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Unfortunately the [MSDN documentation for WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138334(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> This operation will not block.

which seems to not be strictly true.